# Issues in Create Database after installation of Openerp

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I have installed Openerp in my local system using intruction from [here](https://doc.openerp.com/v7.0/install/linux/server/) but after successful installation when I start server and access openeep from browser , I got a screen to create Database but when I tried to do so I am getting server access denied error.

Traceback :

```
OpenERP Server Error

Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 195, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 718, in create
    params['create_admin_pwd'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 28, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20121227_075624-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 95, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault('AccessDenied', str(e))


Server Access denied.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this is because of OpenERP is not allowing you to create database because your master password is incorrect.

Make sure your master password is same as you defined. By default in field there will be password as "admin" so if you have changed your password then change password field in master password.

Tell me if its still giving error.

Comment: Yes  It works , I thought the master password field getting password from my browser saved passwords and I was trying other pass passwords

Comment: On a sort of related note, what are my options if we lost the master password.